How to compute this large Stirling number in an acceptable time?
I need to compute S(114514,100), which is a large Stirling number (see definition here)
I tried Mathematica, Maple, and Scipy (in python), but neither of these software managed to give the result in 10 hours. By an approximation formula, the number has about 231000 digits. I believe there are several possibilities:

My computer is not powerful enough. I need another device.
The algorithm in those software are not good enough.

So is there any way I can get the result?

Simple question: why do you "need" to compute that number? What are you doing that requires that exact number as a number, rather than as symbolic expression in a larger expression that you can simplify to something that is both meaningful and computable?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Why? Because large integers are fun is a good enough reason, to be honest.

Indeed, so let's wait for them to explain why they need this, because that changes the kind of answer that'll best help them.

Maybe the attempts you tried use simple recursion which won't work well for such a big number. If you code the summation shown in the linked page,S(n,k) = (1/k!)sum_{i=0 to k} (-1)^i(kCi)(k-i)^n, I think you should get a result in reasonable time and have reasonable space requirements..

@SimonGoater No, I just used built-in functions. For example, in Mathematica, StirlingS2[114514,100] It is surprising that it doesn't work whereas implementing it ourselves do.

A naive implementation of the sum series for Stirling number in Python (which has unlimited precision integers) takes ~2 seconds on an M2 Mac, and the result has 228872 digits.
import math

def st(n, k):
    m = 1
    s = 0

    for i in range(k+1):
        z = math.comb(k, i) * (k - i) ** n
        s += m * z
        m = -m

    return s // math.factorial(k)  # explicit integer division

r = st(114514, 100)
print(f"st(114514, 100) has {int(math.log10(r))+1} digits")


I've updated the code to also explicitly print the number of digits, but that reports 228871 (which would be in line with what Robert reports, too), rather than 228872.

For the record, I find that Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) can find S(114514, 100) in a reasonable time. Maxima relies on the underlying Common Lisp implementation (SBCL here) to do arithmetic -- it seems likely that any system working with multi-word integers, as Lisp implementations do, can likewise work.
(%i2) stirling2 (114514, 100) $

(%i3) bfloat (%);
(%o3)               1.071510288125467b228870

This result takes about 5 seconds on a middling desktop computer. I have suppressed the display of the result with the dollar sign terminator on the input %i2 since the result is has a lot of digits.
bfloat is a software multi-word float; %o3 shows the result has 228871 digits.
I am working with a recent development build of Maxima, but I think any not-too-ancient version should be able to do the same calculation.
